# check change number if it has changed refresh page

Tags: javascript

I'm thinking about how to achieve this if the number changes

(increase the number) so that the page refreshes?

```
    const actual = document.querySelector("#incomings_amount").innerText;
console.log(actual) = 1

setInterval(

    function() {
                window.location.reload();
            }, (Math.random() * 80000) + 900000);
```

this gives, for example, a value of 1

and if the number changes as soon as I get the number checked if it has changed and
if yes

to Web refresh?

Comment: Please consider the question you have asked and try to make it very clear what you are trying to accomplish. Your code doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Kinglish if the number changes i want the page to refresh

Comment: SO you want to listen to an input element and if the user types in a number other than 1, the page refreshes?

Comment: Or actually, how does the number change? where does that action come from?

Comment: @Kinglish  it's a number from the web

if it changes there to make the web refresh       const actual = `document.querySelector("#incomings_amount").innerText;` ( this give number example )  if it changes they need to be refreshed

Comment: @Kinglish  it is a number in a random range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const el = document.querySelector("#incomings_amount")
let original = el.innerText

setTimeout(() => {
  el.innerText = "55"
}, 5000)

let watcher = setInterval(() => {
  if (el.innerText.toString().trim() !== original.trim().toString()) {
    console.log("RELOAD!!");
    clearInterval(watcher)
  }
}, 200);
```

```html
<div id="incomings_amount">45</div>
<p>... wait 5 seconds and this will change...</p>
```